# Error in converting excel data to Json string. FileReader.onload not working

Tags: angular, angular7, npm-install, filereader, openxlsx

I am Using XLSX npm package to read the data from Excel and convert into JSON format

I'm using Angular 7.

```js
     const reader = new FileReader();
     const file = ev.target.files[0];
     reader.onload = (event) => {
       const data = reader.result;
       console.log(data);
       workBook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
       jsonData = workBook.SheetNames.reduce((initial, name) => {
         const sheet = workBook.Sheets[name];
         initial[name] = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
         return initial;
       }, {});
       const dataString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
     };
```

Tried using *reader.onload* and *reader.onloadend*, it's not even throwing an error but the events are not firing.
Can anyone help how to make it work?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/xlsx-to-json-7razm6?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
 onFileChange(ev) {
    let workBook = null;
    let jsonData = null;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const file = ev.target.files[0];
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      const data = reader.result;
      workBook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
      jsonData = workBook.SheetNames.reduce((initial, name) => {
        const sheet = workBook.Sheets[name];
        initial[name] = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
        return initial;
      }, {});
      const dataString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = dataString.slice(0, 300).concat("...");
      this.setDownload(dataString);
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The events are not firing because you are not calling any read method on your file object . You need to call one of the read methods on your file object for one of the events to get fired.

The file reader read methods are -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Methods

And the event handlers are -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Event_handlers

You can read more about the usage of reader methods by clicking on one of them eg-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Basically , In your code  you just need to add some read method at the end like -

```
     const reader = new FileReader();
     const file = ev.target.files[0];
     reader.onload = (event) => {
       const data = reader.result;
       console.log(data);
       workBook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
       jsonData = workBook.SheetNames.reduce((initial, name) => {
         const sheet = workBook.Sheets[name];
         initial[name] = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
         return initial;
       }, {});
       const dataString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
     };

    // ADD THIS IN YOUR CODE
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```